# Scala - change/add behaviour to a static method

Tags: scala, static-methods

is it possible to change/add behaviour to a static method? I mean add/change behaviour like AspectJ does (before, after...). I have been using the [Scala's Stackable Trait Pattern](http://www.artima.com/scalazine/articles/stackable_trait_pattern.html) to change behaviour of methods from classes and traits like AspectJ(but i am not using it or intend to use AspectJ, just want to emulate the same functionality) but this doesn´t work for objects and, as such, for static methods neither). Do you know a way to make this work? Thanks in advance to any help/advice. Let me know if you need an example or something.

Answer (score -1):

Scala doesn't really have static methods. The compiler will create static methods, but these aren't a visible language feature. For an `object`, Scala creates static methods for Java interop, all they do is invoke the corresponding methods on the singleton instance. For a trait with concrete methods, Scala compiles those methods into static methods, which are the invoked from instance methods created in each class that extends the trait.

In order to use AspectJ on an `object`, you have to give it the class name for that object. This will be whatever name it has in Scala but with a `$` appended, e.g. `List$` is the class name of the companion object for `List`. To use AspectJ with a trait, append `$class` to the trait name to get the class where the static methods for the trait live.

Comment: "For a trait with concrete methods, Scala compiles those methods into static methods", you mean the methods defined in the companion object or it transforms the methods in the trait to static methods?(and in this way, those methods can be acessed statically). I am not intending to use AspectJ, just want to capture a call to a method defined in an object and add something before or after it is executed. With classes and Traits you can do that with Stackable Trait Pattern. The only solution i am thinking by your answer is to define the method that i want in the trait and(continue next comment)

Comment: (continue) and use the companion object to turn it in a static method. Don´t know if the pattern will work though, since i need to mixin the class that owns the method with the stackable trait that overrides it behaviour, but the method will be called from the companion object, not an instance of that class. So no mixin can be done.

Comment: Yes, concrete methods in traits become static methods. It sounds to me like you should write a trait and mix it into the companion object rather than the class itself, though a more concrete example would help to answer your question.